# What is the union of bitfield equivalent in Dart?

Tags: dart, union, bit-fields

I'd like to achieve the following C code in Dart:

```c
union AuxiliaryHardwares {
  uint16_t all = 0;

  struct {
    hasRs485: 1;
    hasCanbus: 1;
    hasRelay0: 1;
    hasRelay1: 1; 
  };
};

AuxialiaryHardwares ah;

ah.all = 123; // Or any value I read from the network

if (ah.hasCanbus) {
  // blah blah
}
if (ah.hasRelay0) {
  // blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no language support for accessing individual bits of an integer as an integer or boolean variable.

Traditionally, you'd write it yourself.

```dart
class AuxiliaryHardwares {
  static const int _rs485Flag = 1; 
  static const int _canbusFlag = 2;
  static const int _relay0Flag = 4;
  static const int _relay1Flag = 8;

  int all = 0;  

  bool get hasRs45 => all & _rs45Flag != 0;
  bool get hasCanbus => all & _canbusFlag != 0;
  bool get hasRelay0 => all & _relay0Flag != 0;
  bool get hasRelay1 => all & _relay1Flag != 0;

  // Setters too if you want them, e.g.
  void set hasRs45(bool value) {
    all = value ? (all | _rs45Flag) : (all & ~_rs45Flag);
  }
}
```

You can probably find a bit-set class somewhere which abstracts over accessing individual bits of an integer, but it'll be extra overhead for very little gain.

I expect that "inline classes" will be the future way to encapsulate integers like this.